# Disabling EWF protection on Win7 Embedded

Tags: windows-7, embedded

I'm using the following command on a HP thin client running Microsoft Windows Embedded Standard 7 to commit data and disable the EWF without rebooting:

```
ewfmgr c: -commitanddisable -live
```

I'm using the RAM overlay mode, and based on the msdn documentation found on the MSDN webiste, the command is supported.

When calling the command with administrator rights, all I can see is `***Committing data and disabling overlay` and that's it.. it simply gets stuck at this point. The ewfmgr.exe process has 50% CPU usage all the time and there's no way I can kill it. The only solution is to reboot.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there any other way of disabling the EWF without rebooting first?

Thanks.

Comment: does the same issue happen if you don't commit and disable LIVE? (eg: ewfmgr c: -commitanddisable, then reboot)